# how to pass a dynamic array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have dynamically loaded the values of checkbox using php, n m using AJAX in that page to call the processing page.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="javascript:wait1();getPass('go.php?**place**='+ document.form1.place.value);" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input name="place[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$ro['article_title']?>" /><?=$ro['article_title']?>
```

As the checkbox consists of arrays, I do not get the values.

Plz help..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the question... the checkbox value is an array?

Comment: The checkboxes are generated depending on the database values and are inside the while loop. So, i've defined its name in array as place[].

Now, when I put place[] in the javasript... it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "array style" to access the form's properties, like `form1['place[]']`. As this is a checkbox, several values can be selected and `form1['place[]']` will return a node list. You could build the URL by traversing through the list:

```
var places = document.form1['place[]'];

var checked_places = [];
for (var i = 0, l = places.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (places[i].checked) {
        checked_places.push('place[]=' + places[i].value);
    }
}
var url = "go.php?" + checked_places.join('&');
```

See a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrYBz/1/

But why do it like that? As you are POSTing the form anyway, why not just read the values via `$_POST` on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

To quote [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters,
>   digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
>   periods (".").

So `[` and `]` are not valid inside the `name` attribute.

Comment: But they are often used when you use PHP as server side language to indicate that an array of values should be created: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php